# Can't find table "cdc.lsn_time_mapping"

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a legacy system that have a call to this function (sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn), and I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid object name 'cdc.lsn_time_mapping'
```

I couldn't find this table on Object Explorer. Is there any replacement for this function or do I need to have any special permission to access it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your database enabled for CDC? You can check this with a look in the `sys.databases` system table. Look for the is_cdc_enabled column; it will be 1 if your database has CDC enabled.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was disabled.If you want, you can answer it and I will mark as correct.

Comment: [Enable and Disable Change Data Capture (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, CDC was not enabled for the OPs database. Enabling it will create this table (among other objects).

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, I was getting the same error in MSSQL Server Management Studio because I had the wrong database selected.

Also if you query sys.databases

```
SELECT name, is_cdc_enabled 
FROM sys.databases
```

and it's not enabled.  You can enable CDC by executing:

`exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_db`